# Spring Batch ExitCodeGenerator on exception throws in tasklet

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, error-handling, spring-batch

In my Spring Batch Application I would like to return a different exit code according to the Exception thrown.

So I followed this documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-exit

and implements the ExitCodeGenerator in my exception :

```
class MyCustomException(message: String) : RuntimeException(message), ExitCodeGenerator {
    override fun getExitCode(): Int {
        return 13
    }

}
```

This exception is thrown in a tasklet, and the application is run like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    exitProcess(
        SpringApplication.exit(
            runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
        )
    )
}
```

but when the exception is thrown, the application failed with an exit code 5. It seems the exceptions in steps are not propagated to the SpringApplication.run() that checks the exception exit codes. Is this Spring Boot feature incompatible with the Spring batch behavior or do I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

> implements the ExitCodeGenerator in my exception

The exception type should not be an `ExitCodeGenerator`, it should rather be the  other way around: The `ExitCodeGenerator` should return an exit code based on the exception type.

Spring Boot emits a `JobExecutionEvent` with the `JobExecution`, so you can make your custom `ExitCodeGenerator` a listener to this type of event, something like:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobExecutionEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(
                SpringApplication.exit(
                        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)
                )
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        Step step = new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    throw new Exception("Boom");
                }, transactionManager).build();
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator () {
        return new MyExitCodeGenerator();
    }

    static class MyExitCodeGenerator implements ExitCodeGenerator, ApplicationListener<JobExecutionEvent> {

        private JobExecution jobExecution;

        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            ExitStatus exitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus();
            if (ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode().equals(exitStatus.getExitCode())) {
                return 13;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(JobExecutionEvent jobExecutionEvent) {
            this.jobExecution = jobExecutionEvent.getJobExecution();
        }
    }

}
```

If you run this app, the exit code of the process should be 13. The project was generated from start.spring.io with this [link](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=batch,h2).